# Выражение "отслюнить пару косарей"

Tags: значения, идиомы

Что значит *отслюнить пару косарей*?

Comment: [SE:Rus Косарь: сколько это и почему так называется?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/47466/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

Comment: О названии "косарь" можно прочесть здесь: http://fb.ru/article/146760/kosar---skolko-eto-deneg-istoriya-poyavleniya-i-znachenie-jargonizma

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Я полагаю, *заплатить пару тысяч*. Либо *отсчитать пару тысяч*.
Здесь:

- отслюнить - как мне представляется, основано на том, что некоторые слюнявят пальцы, отсчитывая купюры.
- косарь - это тысяча.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Слово "отслюнит" придумал, наверное, Галич.  "И кассир мне деньгу отслюнит по рублю..."

Comment: Ruscorpora находит использование в 1932, Стругацкие использовали в 1971, а Галич вроде как в 1970, скорее всего уже было в широком ходу.

Answer (score -4):

Отслюнявить - значение слова уходит далико в историю. Тогда "ходили" деньги, так называимые "чешуйки". Крестьяне не могли себе позволить обзавестись кошелем, ну а карманов небыло, в связи с етим деньги носили во рту. И когда нужно было воспользоватся деньгами они доставали их изо рта - "отслюнявливали"!!!

Comment: Подтверждается ли это какими-то источниками?